Kotlin 1.9.2, jdk 21 (Spring boot) Jacoco (plugin 0.8.12) is complaining about missing branches
I have run into a jacoco code coverage issue where it complains about missing branches for the kotlin coroutines function withContext(Dispatchers.IO) event though all branches are covered. Nothing fancy in my code it tries to load the authenticated user and returns non null Long value which is already covered.
Jacoco keeps complaining about it.
    suspend fun resolveLoggedUserId(): Long = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
       //...execute code base
        
    }


This also happens for my generic function when I invoke it from actual methods:
suspend fun <T : Any> withLoggedUser(
    context: Context,
    block: suspend (Long) -> T,
): T = with(context) {
    block()
}

example:
suspend fun doStuff(
        request:Request,
    ): Response =
        withLoggedUser(context = request.context) { loggedUser ->
            Response.newBuilder()
                .setId(loggedUserId)
                .setAvailable(service.isAvailable(loggedUser))
                .build()
        }

It complains about missing branches at the withLoggedUser(context = request.context) level (most likely null value) while the actual method returns non null.
Is this a knowning issue with jacoco not filtering such method.
You might also notice that I have also forced my generic upper bound T to Any and not Any? and nothing changes.

Solution:
I was not passing any suspend function that 's why it is complaining, but otherwise it works now.(See my last comment) and this jacoco


Note: I could not filter out the claasses that are comlaining about this issue because it will be lots of uncovered code which is critical for the applications' healthy status.

Without Complete Minimal Reproducible Example hard to say for sure, but this looks very similar to https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1383 - for suspending lambdas without suspension points (i.e. without invocations of suspending functions/lambdas) JaCoCo 0.8.12 shows missed branch, this is planned to be fixed in future JaCoCo version - https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/1283

Thanks @Goding this also happens for jacoco 0.8.11. Do you know when the fix will be available.
Is there any work around without excluding these classes or lowering the coverage?

I tried to use jacoco plugin 0.8.10 and 0.8.9 and I got the same result.

This issue I was facing is that I was not testing at any time my block of code with an actual supend function.
I fixed it by passing a suspend function block of code.
Thanks to my colleague of work
